# Assign image to cell in CollectionViewController

Tags: swift

I am using Xcode 9.2 and Swift 4.0

I have a UICollectionViewController that Xcode has generated for me. I have customized it a bit and my code sort of looks like this.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var images = [UIImage(named: “image1“), [UIImage(named: “image2“), [UIImage(named: “image3“)]

//stuff deleted
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    code
   }
}
```

I had expected there to be an image property on the cell below, so this is the Swift I thought I would be writing.

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var images = [UIImage(named: “image1“), [UIImage(named: “image2“), [UIImage(named: “image3“)]

//stuff deleted
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.image = images[indexPath.row] //this doesn’t compile
   }
}
```

The code does not compile.

Yes I have tried to solve this myself but most examples on the web, including here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497263/why-are-image-views-sometimes-not-appearing-in-collection-view-cells), seem to show something very similar to what I want yet does compile.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By default `UICollectionViewCell` doesn't have `image` property. You need to cast it to your type if it have such property or create `UIImageView` with given image and add it to the cell.